# oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout and Socket read timed out

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, jboss

Sometimes I'm getting the below error on my application running on jboss 7 with DBCP .
I would like to understand : does it means oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout is configure on my application or not ? how can I check what is oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout value ?

```
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Socket read timed out
            at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:320)
            at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:103)
            at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:230)
            at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:175)
            at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:100)
            at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:85)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:122)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:78)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1179)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1155)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:279)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:521)
```

Comment: more details please: when does this happen?

Comment: I unterstand that in PipedReader class in the receive method in the code try {
                wait(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                throw new java.io.InterruptedIOException();
            }:   it happen. but who throw the InterruptedException  ? is it a jboss thread ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your first question is yes. If you're seeing this exception, then the read timeout property must be set. By default there is no read timeout and so you would never see this exception.

The answer to your second question is 'it depends'. The read timeout can be set as a system property with `-D` in the command line. It can also be set through a `DataSource` property. Try to `grep` for `oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout` in your scripts.

Comment: can not ( not allowed