# getting data from Db to front end using jdbc.. eclipse,oracle

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to get data from Db to front end using jdbc.. eclipse, oracle
I tried many solutions but none of them resolved.
I am facing below issue

```
IO:socket time out
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Socket read timed out
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:673)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:715)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:385)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:30)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:564)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at com.HRCore_IAT.Servlet1.doGet(Servlet1.java:38)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:509)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Socket read timed out
        at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:350)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolStream.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolStream.java:153)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:263)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1360)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:486)
        ... 30 more
```

I am able to connect through `SQL*plus` and even connection was established(confirmed with basic jdbc program).

**NOTE:** i am not sysdba and DB is on other machine its all under VPN,firewalls. Someone please help me to get out of this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you verify the setting of http://stackoverflow.com/a/34589883?

Comment: Please show the code you use, or at minimum the connection string used.

Comment: Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip adress:1521/xe", "xxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxx");